# Appending large number of data frames efficiently in pyspark

Tags: python, scala, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a dictionary of large number of data frames,Ii plan to union them all to store in dbfs, tried following:

```
***df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([],schema)
for i in dict.keys():
  df = df.union(dict[i])***
```

This is taking ages to execute! Is there a efficient way to merge them ? I am assuming I am going ((((a+b)+c)+d)+e).... which is why more time

Comment: was that answer helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataFrames can only be merged one by one, but you can do a union on rdd-s, and then convert final one back to dataframe:

```
def unionAll(dict, schema):
    dfs = dict.values()
    firstDf = dfs[0]
    return firstDf.sql_ctx.createDataFrame(
        firstDf.sql_ctx._sc.union([df.rdd for df in dfs]),
        schema
    )
```

According to http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/repeated-unioning-of-dataframes-take-worse-than-O-N-2-time-td20394.html#a20408, you should get some increase in speed, as Spark won't be going through analysis stage for previous df-s each time.